# How to add custom HTTP headers into a AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate loading request

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I need to add a custom HTTP header to the media loading request when loading an `AVURLAsset`, from `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`'s `resourceLoader(:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:)`.

The `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest`'s `request` is an immutable property, so calling `addValue(...)` on it is not possible.

There's a `redirect` request property on `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest`, which could in theory be used as the original request plus the necessary headers, but it seems to have no effect (i.e. the request that is made doesn't have the custom headers).

**Edit**: as I've suspected, the `resourceLoader(:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:)` callback is being called after the `loadingRequest.request` has been dispatched.

**Edit 2**: So `AVURLAsset` does have the `AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey` options key, which lets one add custom cookies, but not arbitrary HTTP headers, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of the `resourceLoader(:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:)` method, you should have something like the following code:

```
// somehow create the URLRequest that you need with the correct headers
let redirectRequest: URLRequest
loadingRequest.redirect = redirectRequest
loadingRequest.finishLoading

// tell the resource loader that you know how it should handle the request
return true
```

It's kind of a strange interface and the documentation could be clearer, but I think that's basically what you need.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your answer. Ultimately we've decided to go with an embedded proxy server, as described here - https://github.com/kevinjameshunt/AVPlayer-HTTP-Headers-Example

Comment: This will not work for segment requests. Those headers are not picked up for whatever reason.

Comment: Unfortunately all headers are discarded and will never reach the server